# Finding the max difference between every combination of rows of a group and the group preceding it

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a dataframe like this

```
Order   Value   Placement   Group
0         9       high        1
1         10      high        1
2         10      high        1
5         3       low         2
6         4       low         2
7         7       high        3
9         1       low         4
10        8       high        5
11        9       high        5
```

I would like find the highest difference value for each row of a group between combinations with every row of the previous group, and which 'Order' value the highest difference was found with. The desired output would be something like

```
Order   Value   Placement   Group   Highest Diff   Found With
5         3       low         2          7             2
6         4       low         2          6             2
7         7       high        3          4             5
9         1       low         4          6             7
10        8       high        5          7             9
11        9       high        5          8             9
```

I've used df.groupby(df['group']) to group the similar Placement values together, but I can't figure out how to use .diff() between the contents of the groups and get the .max() of the values it finds.